# Dell OMSA Authentication Fail on Ubuntu

Tags: dell-poweredge, pam, ubuntu-8.04, dell-openmanage

I am trying to log into an install of Dell OMSA 5 on a Dell PowerEdge 2850 running Ubuntu 8.04 LTS x64.

OMSA is 32bit and is trying to load the 64bit pam modules for authentication. Whatever credentials I use to authenticate with via the OMSA web interface at https://myserver.com:1311 I always receive a "Login failed..." message and the following errors in `/var/log/auth.log`

```
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib32/security/pam_unix.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib32/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by /lib32/security/pam_unix.so)]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib32/security/pam_unix.so
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_env.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib/security/pam_env.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_env.so
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_unix.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib/security/pam_unix.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_unix.so
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_ldap.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib/security/pam_ldap.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_ldap.so
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_mkhomedir.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib/security/pam_mkhomedir.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_mkhomedir.so
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_lastlog.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib/security/pam_lastlog.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_lastlog.so
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_motd.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib/security/pam_motd.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_motd.so
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_mail.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib/security/pam_mail.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_mail.so
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_limits.so)
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM [error: /lib/security/pam_limits.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64]
Apr 26 14:47:48 server dsm_om_connsvc32d: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_limits.so
```

I have the following in `/etc/pam.d/omauth`;

```
root@server:/var/log# cat /etc/pam.d/omauth 
#%PAM-1.0
#auth       required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
#auth       required    /lib32/security/pam_nologin.so
#account    required    pam_stack.so service=system-auth

auth       required     /lib32/security/pam_unix.so nullok
auth       required     /lib32/security/pam_nologin.so
auth       required /lib32/security/pam_ldap.so nullok
account    required     /lib32/security/pam_unix.so nullok
```

I have downloaded and unpacked the 32bit pam modules into `/lib32/security`. Is there anyway I can authenticate with these for OMSA (but not the anything else)?

```
root@server:/lib32/security# ls
pam_ldap.so  pam_nologin.so  pam_unix.so
root@server:/lib32/security# file pam_unix.so 
pam_unix.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), stripped
root@server:/lib32/security# file pam_ldap.so 
pam_ldap.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), stripped
root@server:/lib32/security# file pam_nologin.so 
pam_nologin.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), stripped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to resolve this was to remove OMSA, and all dependencies, I peformed a dist upgrade and start again. I couldn't find the root cause or solution.